# Is there a shop at the Ballads Oratory?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

When I reached the Ballads Oratory as part of the Ballad of Bloody Bones quest my backpack was completely full, so I was delighted to see that the map showed there was a shop inside. However I talked to everyone inside and no one offered the "shop" option.

Is this a bug, or is there something I need to do in order to use the Ballads Oratory shop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shopkeeper is outside, around the left side of the building.

[image]